# What is a C++ object of the type vector<char,allocator<char> > and how can it be used?

Tags: c++, vector, char, allocator

I have a C++ object of the type `vector<char,allocator<char> >`. Conceptually, I expect it to be a list of Boolean values. How should I access it (for example, to print the Boolean value of each of its elements)?

Comment: What's the problem of using vector<bool>?

Comment: or [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert from `char` to `bool`?

Comment: What gave you the expectation that a `vector<char>` would be "a list of Boolean values"? Where did you get that idea from? I'm not going to put together an answer until I can understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use range `for`, you can use:

```
for ( auto el : v )
{
    // Use el
}
```

If you are still using C++03, you can use:

```
vector<char,allocator<char> >::const_iterator iter = v.begin();
vector<char,allocator<char> >::const_iterator end = v.end();
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
{
   char el = *iter;
   // Use el
}
```

Comment: `iter !+ end` that's a new one

Comment: There is never a need to explicitly specify the allocator type when using `std::allocator` with a data type that is the same as the `vector`'s data type. `std::vector`'s template parameters have a default declaration for the allocator type, eg: `template<class _Ty, class _Ax = allocator<_Ty> > class vector {...};`.  Thus, the variable declarations above can be simplified to this: `vector<char>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); vector<char>::const_iterator end = v.end();`